# Rcpp: static_assert failed due to requirement '! sizeof(double *) " cannot convert type to SEXP"

Tags: c++, r, c, rcpp

I am using Rcpp to write an R package
But I met a problem when building the package

It told me
[image: Error message]

`static_assert failed due to requirement '! sizeof(double *) " cannot convert type to SEXP"`

I didn't understand this error message. Why this is an error
I guess it is due to the pointer.

Here are my codes

```
double * rxkcd(double stdc,int n){
    static double rnd[MAX_LENGTH];
    double a=0;
    static double b[MAX_LENGTH];
    int i;
    for ( i = 0; i < n; ++i)
      {
          b[i]=pdf_normal(*(getmultinormal(stdc,n)+i),stdc);
      }
    
    for ( i = 0; i < n; ++i)
      {
          rnd[i] = (double) rand()/RAND_MAX * (b[i]-a) + a;
      }
    return(rnd);
}
```

Can anyone tell me why this happens? I am a beginner using Rcpp.

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, it is due to the pointer. Where did you read that you can have a function return a pointer like that with Rcpp? You need to return something that can be passed to R. Also, please include the `#include`s in your example.

Comment: Thank you so much! Solved! I use NumericVector instead of a pointer. Is this a common way to handle vectors by using Rcpp?